# How to stop recompiling in the middle of the run

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I am running some deep learning experiments, and I am having some weird and unfortunate issues that destroyed 3 of my hours of experimental runs...

When I am running a code I believe it gets compiled at the beginning of the run and when I edit the code it is supposed to run as it was when I first ran it. But seems like when I edit some parts of the code get recompiled (or whatever is happening) and stops my experiment (Throws an error depending on the current state of the code). My question is, is this normal, how do compiling work in Python, what could I do to fix this issue?

Here I will give a little more info on the system I am using;

- I am running the experiments using **tmux**
- I am using a **Linux** server, remotely connected on **VSCode**
- My code is in **Python3.8**

Any other information you think is needed, please let me know and I will try to add it.

**Edit**
Adding an example;

If I run this chunk of code for the first experiment I have;

```py
model = proxy_cnn(10, 100)
```

And I change it while the execution is not yet completed, to let's say

```py
model = proxy_cnn_2(10, 100)
print('Here')
```

The code starts executing the new version and gives me the new print I added (if it doesn't stop working) with the new model that I was setting for the next experiment...

Comment: "break my experiment" - _how exactly_ does the experiment "break"?

Comment: Gives an error. Basically assumes that the code is in the current version (in the middle of editing) and throws a syntax error or whatever it is that is wrong at the moment @ForceBru

Comment: @Bedir Tapkan -Could you please provide us with an example that can minimize the recurrence of this problem? In addition, when running the code in VS Code, it calls the system's python to execute the python file.

Comment: @JillCheng Sorry for the late reply. I added an example that I think might help with the understanding. About execution, I was actually asking if the system is executing the code again and again while running (which makes no sense I am aware) or if not how am I getting this error.